# Git Renaming Branches Remote and Local

Tags: git

Currently I am naming my branches using an issue number first, but when using the git CLI it puts the branches in alphabetical order, resulting in the 1 and 2 digit issue numbers showing up in the wrong place. If I make all the branch names 3 digits the branch number will order correctly. Its kinda a minor thing, but it’s an easy way to improve organization and readability.

Can anyone think of a reason why it might be a bad idea to create all future branches with 3 digits as standard?

So instead of

17-BRANCHNAME_1

017-BRANCHNAME_1

Furthermore, to implement this change (we have over 100 misnamed branches at this point), does the following make sense?

1. Create a script to run on a central system that renames all REMOTE branches to the correct name
2. Create a script to run on every contributors local repository that renames all LOCAL branches and updates their trackers

Will I run into any issues doing this? I don't want to break the repository and I'm still not extremely well acquainted with Git

Comment: My question would be why you have over 100 issue branches open. Do you have a very large team? Are issues being started and not completed? Are you leaving the issue branches around after they're done?

Comment: It's a large project. Issues are not being completed in this phase.

Comment: They're not being completed, but they're being worked on?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: So folks are working on 100 issues which are not this phase, and meanwhile the issue branches remain open and unmerged? I suspect an improved process would reduce the number of open issue branches dramatically. If you asked a question about your process we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing technically wrong with your proposal. However, it takes a lot of coordination to change hundreds of checked out branches across what I can only assume is dozens of developers.

I would suggest you change the naming convention for new branches, but leave the existing branches as they are. If they're proper issue branches they should close in a few weeks. This will save a lot of hassle.

Meanwhile, use `sort -g` to sort your branches on the CLI. This will sort leading numbers correctly.

```
git branch | sort -g
```

---

If you must do this, it's probably better to have the individuals working on their issue branches change both the local and remote branches. This ensures their local branches are coordinated with the new remotes.

```
# Checkout an issue branch.
git checkout <branch>

# Rename the local branch.
git branch -m <new name>

# Push the new branch
git push origin -u <new name>

# Delete the old remote branch
git push origin --delete <old name>
```

You can probably turn this into a little script folks can run which looks for local issue branches and performs the rename.